# Clearcase server move with IP change - Clearcase client views with fix IP

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

The ClearCase server was moved to another building, host name the same, IP changed. Also, the ClearCase client was moved, host name the same, new IP.

The problem is now that some of the views cannot find the ClearCase server, because the views have the old IP in the file .view, not the host name of the server.

How can this be fixed?

Note: I tried and changed the old IP in the view file to the host name: no success.

Answer (score 0):

> Changed the old IP in the view file to the host name, no success

But did you reboot, or at least restart ClearCase? (`net stop albd` on Windows, `/etc/init.d/atria stop` on Linux)

Check if updating vob/view tags is enough (validate that you can access `NEW_HOST_PATH` with a simple `dir`/`ls`):

```bash
cleartool mktag -vob -replace -host NEW_HOSTNAME -hpath NEW_HOST_PATH -gpath NEW_GLOBAL_PATH VOB_TAG_NAME
cleartool mktag -view -replace -host NEW_HOSTNAME -hpath NEW_HOST_PATH -gpath NEW_GLOBAL_PATH VIEW_TAG_NAME
```

But generally, official procedures like "[Moving a view to a host with a different architecture](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/9.0.0?topic=view-moving-host-different-architecture)" would require `cleartool rmtag –view –all` + `cleartool unregister –view` for all views, before registering them and tagging them again.

Those commands are run on the ClearCase server, with:

- `NEW_HOSTNAME` refers to the hostname of the system where the VOB or view storage is located. That is generally the ClearCase server's hostname.
- `NEW_HOST_PATH` refers to the location of the VOB or view storage on the host system. That would be the path on the ClearCase server where the VOB or view storage resides.
  For example, if your VOB storage is located at `/net/storage/vobs/myvob.vbs` on the server, then `NEW_HOST_PATH` would be `/net/storage/vobs/myvob.vbs`.
- `NEW_GLOBAL_PATH` refers to the network-accessible location of the VOB or view storage, which can be accessed from any client machine. It might be a UNC path (for Windows) or an NFS path (for Unix) that points to the VOB or view storage location on the server.
  For instance, if clients access the VOB storage using a network path like `\\server_name\net\storage\vobs\myvob.vbs`, then `NEW_GLOBAL_PATH` would be `\\server_name\net\storage\vobs\myvob.vbs`.
- `VOB_TAG_NAME` and `VIEW_TAG_NAME` refer to the tag names associated with your VOB and view respectively. Tags are aliases that are used to reference the VOBs and views in ClearCase commands.

Example

```bash
cleartool mktag -vob -replace -host server_name -hpath /net/storage/vobs/myvob.vbs -gpath \\server_name\net\storage\vobs\myvob.vbs myvob_tag

cleartool mktag -view -replace -host server_name -hpath /net/storage/views/myview.vws -gpath \\server_name\net\storage\views\myview.vws myview_tag
```

Where:

- `server_name` is the hostname of the ClearCase server.
- `/net/storage/vobs/myvob.vbs` and `/net/storage/views/myview.vws` are the host paths to the VOB and view storages on the server.
- `\\server_name\net\storage\vobs\myvob.vbs` and `\\server_name\net\storage\views\myview.vws` are the global paths accessible from the client machines.
- `myvob_tag` and `myview_tag` are the VOB and view tag names respectively.

---

The [OP Tom Rossi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9652379/tom-rossi) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77096107/clearcase-server-move-with-ip-change-clearcase-client-views-with-fix-ip/77096646#comment135967404_77096646):

> To connect the CC server is not the problem, only IP changed the name is still the same.
> One of the users create manually a snap view and entered the IP of the client, not the hostname of the client.
>
> We have 1 client with the Jenkins plug in, on this client the IP changed, and on this client there are some views which points to the old client IP.
>
> ```bash
> for /f %%x in ('hostname') do 
>    set HOSTNAME=%%x 
>    for /d %%x in (.vws) do 
>       cleartool register -replace -view %%x 
>    for /d %%x in (.vbs) do cleartool mktag -view -replace -tag %%~nx \\%HOSTNAME%\viewshare\%%x
> ```

Comment: To run the replace commands, where I have this to do, Clearcase server or Clearcase client?  NEW_HOSTNAME is the clearcase client name? NEW_HOST_PATH is the location of the vob/view? on server or client? What is the NEW_GLOBAL_PATH VOB_TAG_NAME and NEW_GLOBAL_PATH VIEW_TAG_NAME?

Comment: How many hosts are there in this environment. It seems strange to be using raw IP addresses for anything. Are the clients able to look up the server (correctly) by the host name?

Comment: To connect the CC server is not the problem, only IP changed the name is still the same. One of the users create manually a snap view and entered the IP of the client not the hostname of the client.We have 1 client with the Jenkins plug in, on this client theIP changed and on this client there are some views which points to the old client IP.                    /f %%x in ('hostname') do set HOSTNAME=%%x
for /d %%x in (*.vws) do cleartool register -replace -view %%x
for /d %%x in (*.vbs) do cleartool mktag -view -replace -tag %%~nx \\%HOSTNAME%\viewshare\%%x

Comment: If I see this right only the "broken" views on the clients needs to be repaired with the given commands, right?

Comment: @TomRossi Yes, that should be enough.

Comment: Hi if I run the first line of the command as admin in the consol, /f %%x in ('hostname') do set HOSTNAME=%%x I got "%%x" cannot be processed syntactically at this point. Whats wrong?

Comment: @TomRossi This syntax is meant to be run in a `script.bat` file, not in the CMD

Answer (score 0):

How many hosts are there in this environment? What I've done in the past when I moved VOBs wholesale (or had my registry get "lost" during a "clean" CC install or reinstall) was run a short script like this:

Command Prompt version while in parent directory of .vbs directories:

```
for /f %%x in ('hostname') do set HOSTNAME=%%x
for /d %%x in (*.vbs) do cleartool register -replace -vob %%x
for /d %%x in (*.vbs) do cleartool mktag -vob -replace -tag \%%~nx \\%HOSTNAME%\vobshare\%%x
```

For public VOBs, add -public -password {registry password} before the \%HOSTNAME...

Command prompt version while in parent directory of vws directories:

```
for /f %%x in ('hostname') do set HOSTNAME=%%x
for /d %%x in (*.vws) do cleartool register -replace -view %%x
for /d %%x in (*.vbs) do cleartool mktag -view -replace -tag %%~nx \\%HOSTNAME%\viewshare\%%x
```

This assumes that the server host can talk to the registry server. You may need to confirm the registry server address in the CC control panel before doing it. You will want to SHIFT-RIGHT-CLICK on the control panel applet and select "run as administrator" if you want to be able to make changes that "stick."

Since you're ALSO not getting license errors, that issue was at least straightened out beforehand.

Reregistering and retagging the views will update the .view files.

Comment: Hi, the register action was now done, all fine. But now we have with the Jenkins a problem, if we want to run the build script the following error message pops up

Comment: Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on BUILD_PC9 (ALM_MANAGED_STANDARD) in workspace D:\DEV\CI_P\WS\RSD\PosSW\X1BuildClean
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
[fnfqw_buildclean_latest] $ cleartool lsview -cview -s
[INFO] computeChangeLogBeforeCheckout = false
[INFO] computeChangeLogAfterCheckout  = true
[X1BuildClean] $ cleartool lsview fnfqw_buildclean_latest
  fnfqw_buildclean_latest \\BUILD_PC9\JenkinsViews\fnfqw_buildclean_latest.vws

Comment: Removing view tag because it exists, but the view path doesn't.
[X1BuildClean] $ cleartool rmview -force -tag fnfqw_buildclean_latest
cleartool: Error: Unable to remove \\BUILD_PC9\JenkinsViews\fnfqw_buildclean_latest.vws: Operation not permitted.
cleartool: Error: Unable to remove view \\BUILD_PC9\JenkinsViews\fnfqw_buildclean_latest.vws.

Comment: FATAL: Base ClearCase failed. exit code=1
[X1BuildClean] $ cleartool rmtag -view fnfqw_buildclean_latest

[X1BuildClean] $ cleartool mkview -snapshot -tag fnfqw_buildclean_latest -vws \\10.239.25.149\JenkinsViews\fnfqw_buildclean_latest.vws fnfqw_buildclean_latest
cleartool: Error: Attempt to get location information on \\10.239.25.149\JenkinsViews\fnfqw_buildclean_latest.vws failed: Invalid argument.

Comment: In the c admin console of the Jenkins slave I get 
D:\JenkinsViews\fnfqw_buildclean_latest.vws (no tag in the default region)

What is wrong, permission?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, don't remove and immediately readd a view with the same tag and path. Sometimes things get confused. Use a date stamp in the view and path. Also the message means just that, the view may be registered but isn't tagged.